# How to convert image from SQL Server to string?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework

I have two databases each one in a project (Winforms and web service project), and I have a query with Entity Framework to send data from project 1 to project 2. My problem is how can I convert images from the first database to string to send it via the query?

This is my web service code:

```
// Entity Framework
Person sd = new Person(); 
// Method to get data from winforms app
public void GetData(string name,string picture)
{
    sd.name= name;
    sd.picture= ImageToByteArray(picture);
    context.AddToPerson(sd);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

//Method to save the image into database
private Byte[] ImageToByteArray(string source)
{
    FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(source);
    long sizeByte = fInfo.Length;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(source, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((int)sizeByte);
    return data;
}
```

And this is my Winforms code :

```
WebService3SD.Service1SoapClient oService = new WebService3SD.Service1SoapClient();

private void SendData()
{
    Driver dr = context.Drivers.FirstOrDefault(d => d.name == "name1");
    oService.GetData(dr.name,????);//here i have no idea what i have to do ?!
}
```

For that I need a method to convert the image to a string, so please if someone have any 
idea about that i will be very much appreciated.

Comment: It's clear `GetData` expects `picture` to be a string *representing a path to a file on the server*.  (It is being passed to `FileInfo`'s constructor)  So you aren't "converting an image to a string", but rather need to pass it a path to a file that already exists on the server.  If this is not what you want, you should implement your server so it's not working based off of local paths.

Comment: It seem be a good solution **Kirk** but how can i code that

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to encode the image as Base64 for transfer. Right now your code is trying to read off the server file system. See the code as follows:

In your app that makes the request:

```
private void btnEncode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtInFile.Text))
  {
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(txtInFile.Text, 
                                   FileMode.Open, 
                                   FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] filebytes = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(filebytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
    string encodedData = 
        Convert.ToBase64String(filebytes,                 
                               Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
    txtEncoded.Text = encodedData; 
  }
}
```

On the receiving side:

```
private void btnDecode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtOutFile.Text))
  {
    byte[] filebytes = Convert.FromBase64String(txtEncoded.Text);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(txtOutFile.Text, 
                                   FileMode.CreateNew, 
                                   FileAccess.Write, 
                                   FileShare.None);
    fs.Write(filebytes, 0, filebytes.Length);
    fs.Close(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but where should i put my image in the first method ?